# WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: DevTools returned unknown type:service_worker

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm seeing the following error in a python selenium automated test when running in chrome. The failure is with closing the window, on `driver.close()`. The test is passing without error when I run in Firefox.

I'm using *ChromeDriver 2.10.267517.*

> WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: DevTools returned unknown >type:service_worker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks most probably like a `ChromeDriver Issue`.

You can try with downloading the latest Chrome WebDriver [here](http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.15/)

for you Platform or operating system.

It should work.

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you! Now using `ChomeDriver 2.15`

Comment: This problem has struck again. I have upgraded to latest ChromeDriver version 2.26.0. My Chrome version is 55.0.2883.87. I am still getting this error. I have searched other forums, didn't find any definitive answer.Any idea on the solution?